# How to detect keycode and statemask event in SWT

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to close tip Shell when press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.
I am using SWT in Windows 64 Bit OS. I have made one program to solve this problem but does not detect event at time pressed these key. I have share below code  which I tried.

```
public static void generateTooltip(final TableCursor tableCursor,final Table table) {
    tableCursor.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
            switch (e.detail)
            {
            case SWT.TRAVERSE_ARROW_NEXT:
                if (tip == null)
                    break;
                tip.dispose();
                tip = null;
                break;

            case SWT.TRAVERSE_ARROW_PREVIOUS:
                if (tip == null)
                    break;
                tip.dispose();
                tip = null;
                break;  


            }
        }
    });
    tableCursor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
          public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
          {
              if(((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0) && e.keyCode == SWT.TAB)
              {                  
                  System.out.println("Key down  ALT +TAB Detact!!");
                  if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                            tip.close();
                            tip.dispose();
                    }
              }
          }

          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
          {
              if(((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0) && e.keyCode == SWT.TAB)
              {                  
                  System.out.println("Key down  ALT +TAB Detact!!");
                  if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                            tip.close();
                            tip.dispose();
                    }
              }
          }
    });
    final Listener labelListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            Text label = (Text) event.widget;
            tip = label.getShell();
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SWT.MouseDown:
                    label.setFocus();
                    break;
                case SWT.MouseExit:
                     break;
                case SWT.MouseHover:
                {
                    label.setFocus();
                    break;
                }
                case SWT.MouseEnter:
                {
                    label.setFocus();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    };

    Listener tableListener = new Listener() {
         Text label = null;
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if (event.keyCode == SWT.F3) 
            {   
                if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                    tip.setFocus();
                    label.setFocus();
                }
            }               

            switch (event.type)
            { 

                case SWT.Dispose:
                {
                    if (tip == null)
                        break;
                    tip.dispose();
                    tip = null;
                    label = null;
                    break;
                }

            case SWT.MouseExit: 
            {               
                System.out.println("Mouse Exit");
                if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                        tip.dispose();
                        break;
                }

            }

            case SWT.MouseHover: {
                // for F1 pressed key focus.                
                TableItem item = tableCursor.getRow();                  
                if(item==null)
                    return;
                    if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                        if (!tip.isFocusControl()) {
                            tip.close();
                            tip.dispose();
                        }
                    }

                    if (tableCursor.getRow().getText(tableCursor.getColumn()).equals("")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    tip = new Shell(tableCursor.getShell(), SWT.ON_TOP| SWT.TOOL  | SWT.RESIZE );
                    tip.addTraverseListener( new TraverseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void keyTraversed( TraverseEvent event ) {
                            event.doit = true;
                        }
                    } );
                    tip.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
                    tip.layout(true, true);
                    tip.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 250,205));
                    ScrolledComposite scroll = new ScrolledComposite(tip,SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
                    GridData gd_scrolledComposite = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
                    scroll.setLayoutData(gd_scrolledComposite);
                    scroll.setExpandHorizontal(true);
                    scroll.setExpandVertical(true);
                    scroll.setMinSize(item.getBounds().width,item.getBounds().height);
                    Composite compo = new Composite(scroll, SWT.RESIZE);
                    compo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,true, true, 1, 1));
                    compo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
                    compo.layout(true);
                    scroll.setContent(compo);
                    label = new Text(compo, SWT.RESIZE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);

                    GridData gd_lblNewLabel_2 = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
                    gd_lblNewLabel_2.widthHint = 251;
                    gd_lblNewLabel_2.heightHint = 75;
                    label.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel_2);
                    label.setText(tableCursor.getRow().getText(tableCursor.getColumn()));

                    Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(tip, SWT.NONE);
                    GridData gd_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT,SWT.RIGHT, true, true, 1, 1);
                    lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel_1);
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText("Press F3 to focus");
                    lblNewLabel_1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 250, 205));

                    Label saveTextLabel = new Label(tip, SWT.NONE);
                    GridData gd_savetext = new GridData(SWT.LEFT,SWT.RIGHT, true, true, 1, 1);
                    saveTextLabel.setLayoutData(gd_savetext);
                    saveTextLabel.setText("Press F3 to Save");
                    saveTextLabel.setVisible(false);
                    saveTextLabel.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 250, 205));

                    // / Label lisner called
                    label.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, labelListener);
                    label.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, labelListener);
                    label.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, labelListener);
                    label.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, labelListener);
                    label.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255,250, 205));
                    Rectangle rect = item.getBounds();
                    Point pt = tableCursor.toDisplay(rect.x, rect.y);
                    tip.setBounds(pt.x - rect.x, pt.y - rect.y+ tableCursor.getSize().y, rect.width,rect.height);
                    tip.setVisible(true);
                    tip.pack(true);
                    break;
            }
            case SWT.Close:

            case SWT.MouseMove: 
            {               
                if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                tip.dispose();
                }
            }
            }//End switch
                    }
    };
    tableCursor.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, tableListener);
    tableCursor.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, tableListener);
    table.getShell().addListener(SWT.MouseExit, tableListener);         
    table.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, tableListener);
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work, Windows handles the Alt+Tab and does not give it to the program.

Comment: @greg:when I switch  to different tab via this key, Tool-tip does not  close/dispose please help.